# Run background tasks in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to have a task run in the background of a ReactJS application?

I have an application that consists out of two components. One of these components displays a countdown. I use `setInterval(this.updateTimer, 1000);` to have a function `updateTimer` called, to update the state.
This works as long as the user stays on that component. If the user changes to the other component the following error occurs:
`Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component.`

I understand what the error means and what is causing it.

What I'm looking for is to have the state of that component updated in the background. (Which can't be done since it is unmounted.) Furthermore a notification is displayed when the countdown reaches 0. This also needs to happen, while the component is not mounted.

Is there a concept/helper for something like this? The only solution I could came up with was to have a websocket connection. The timer would run on the back end and via websocket inform the front end when the countdown reaches 0.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah there exist a solution here, **push the state of your timer component up to the parent component**, where both the components are rendered.

Pass timer value, and function to update the time via props to timer component.

No need to store the timer in backend, everything will work as expected. Hope this helps

Comment: I see how this would solve the issue.

What bothers me is, that I would put component specific logic into an component that is (so far) only responsible for routing.
If I add more components later and they might have similar requirements I would put more and more logic into the parent making it harder to maintain.
It would also mean that I can't use the component somewhere else without transferring the logic from the parent component as well.

Comment: Agreed, this would work for smaller application indeed.

Comment: For bigger application try out redux library to handle the logic part, then you will achieve the desired result, consistent data and independent individual components

Comment: I already am using redux. But that still leaves me with the problem of updating the state while the component is not mounted.
Therefore the updating would still have to be done in a parent component.
I don't have a web dev background. Is there a different approach to what I am trying to achieve?